# how to convert hover jquery to js pure?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this code on js:

```
$(".custom-option:first-of-type").hover(function() {
  $(this).parents(".custom-options").addClass("option-hover");
}, function() {
  $(this).parents(".custom-options").removeClass("option-hover");
});
```

but I didn't find anything to convert the hover function to javascript

i have this:

```
const firstOption = document.querySelector(".custom-option:first-of-type");
const customSelectTrigger = document.querySelector(".custom-select-trigger");
const customOption = document.querySelector(".custom-option")

customOption.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  manageOptions(e);
});
customSelectTrigger.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  showOptions(e);
});
function showOptions(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  selectWrap.classList.add("active");
}
function manageOptions(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

my html:

```
        <div class="custom-select-wrapper">
          <select
            name="sources"
            id="sources"
            class="custom-select sources"
            placeholder="Source Type"
          >
            <option value="profile">Profile</option>
            <option value="word">Word</option>
            <option value="hashtag">Hashtag</option>
          </select>
          <div class="custom-select sources">
            <span class="custom-select-trigger">
              Source Type
            </span>
            <div class="custom-options">
              <span class="custom-option undefined">
                profile
              </span>
              <span class="custom-option undefined">
                word
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I need to add a class when the hover event happens, but I wanted to do it for pure js

Comment: use onmouseenter and onmouseleave events instead of click

Answer (score 2):

From the [`hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) docs , the method is basically a shorthand for:

```
$( selector ).mouseenter( handlerIn ).mouseleave( handlerOut );
```

So knowing that you just need to create  event listeners for the events `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`

You could do:

```
['mouseenter','mouseleave'].forEach(eName => {
    firstOption.addEventListener(eName, e => customOption.classList.toggle('option-hover') );
})
```

Comment: but this way I will be removing and adding the  css class?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` and use `classList` to add classes to the element:

```
firstOption.addEventListener('mouseenter', e => {
    customOption.classList.add('option-hover');
});
firstOption.addEventListener('mouseleave', e => {
    customOption.classList.remove('option-hover');
});
```

Comment: `addEventListener()` has no return value so isn't chainable